# R make timeseries data with raw data

Tags: r, graph, time-series, raw-data

I wanna make Timeseries data with raw data

sample data is

```
factor date value
fac1 2011-01 10
fac1 2011-05 20
fac1 2011-07 30
fac2 2011-01 40
fac2 2011-03 50
```

and I wanna make below

```
fac1 2011-01 10
fac1 2011-02 0
fac1 2011-03 20
fac1 2011-04 0
fac1 2011-05 30

.... it goes to 2011-12

fac2 2011-01 40
fac2 2011-02 0
fac2 2011-03 50
fac2 2011-04 0
fac2 2011-05 0

... it goes to 2011-12
```

I wanna show this factors by month and draw graph
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create an expanded dataset the 'factor' and 'date' and then `merge` with the old dataset

```
library(zoo)
df2 <- merge(expand.grid(factor = unique(df1$factor), 
    date= format(seq(as.Date(paste0(date[1],'-01')), length.out=12, 
          by = '1 month'), "%Y-%m")), df1, all.x = TRUE)
```

and assign the `NA` elements in 'value' to 0

```
df2$value[is.na(df2$value)] <- 0
```

Note: No packages used

---

Or a similar option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1, key = c('factor', 'date'))
df1[CJ(factor, date=format(seq(as.Date(paste0(date[1],'-01')), length.out=12, by = '1 month'), 
          format = '%Y-%m'), unique = TRUE)][is.na(value), value := 0][]
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates a multivariate zoo series `z` from `DF` (shown reproducibly in the Note at the end).  `z` has one column per factor and a `yearmon` class index.  It then merges `z` with a zero width series having all the months in order to fill in the empty cells giving `full`. Then we fill in the NAs created by the merge with 0 values using `na.fill`.  This gives `full0` which is like `full` except with the missing months filled in with zeros.

We don't need `long` to create the subsequent plot but because the question asked for it we generate it from `full0` using `ggfortify.zoo` .

Finally we plot `full0` using ggplot2.  Omit `facet = NULL` in `autoplot` if you want each series to be shown in a separate panel.  Also with this small amount of data I found that `breaks = time(full0)` gave a nice axis but if you have more data in reality then you might be able to remove that argument to `scale_x_yearmon`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, index = "date", split = "factor", FUN = as.yearmon)
full <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), 1/12)))
full0 <- na.fill(full, fill = 0)
long <- fortify(full0, melt = TRUE)

autoplot(full0, facet = NULL) + scale_x_yearmon(breaks = time(full0))
```

[image: screenshot]

You could alternately try a classic graphics plot.  Omit `screen=1` if you want a separate panel for each series.

```
plot(full0, screen = 1, col = 1:ncol(full0))
```

**Note:** The input data `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
factor date value
fac1 2011-01 10
fac1 2011-05 20
fac1 2011-07 30
fac2 2011-01 40
fac2 2011-03 50"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me but now I faced problem because I have about 26000 raw data and 720 factors.  It success when I run 1000raws but error occurs when run whole datas.  error message is :series cannot be merged with non-unique index entries in a series

Comment: In the first 1000 series there are no duplicates but evidently one or more of your subsequent series do have duplicate times.  You could add `aggregate = mean` to the `read.zoo` call to collapse any duplicate times to a single point having the mean of the individual values.

Comment: Thanks for helping me^^